# Building xerces using -icu

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, xerces-c

is any body aware of building xerces using icu library , when i am building it giving all icu related option on MacOS its never going for icu option ( it finally says ICU option can not be enabled in config.log ).

```
     ./configure --prefix=/tmp/xer --enable-msgloader-icu --disable-shared --disable-network --enable-static --disable-transcoder-macosunicodeconverter --enable-transcoder-icu --with_icu=/tmp/icu3.5-source/
```

logs says
....
checking whether we can support the iconv Transcoder... yes
checking whether we can support the ICU Transcoder... no
checking for which Transcoder to use (choices: -gnuiconv- -iconv-)... gnuiconv
checking whether we support the InMemory MsgLoader... yes
checking whether we support the ICU MsgLoader... no
checking for nl_types.h... (cached) yes
....

Please could anybody suggest how should I approach this issue, so that I can build the xerces using ICU libs.

Thanks in advance,
brij

Answer (score 1):

look at config.log again - it should tell in some detail you why it 'can't support the ICU Transcoder'

Comment: Figured out from the .log file, that its not able to see libraries which are statically built and it's name should be changed to -lsi<>. which I changed and then there were some versioning issue which was causing all symbols to be represented with version. 
I was able to resolve and it worked fine then.

Comment: All symbols represented with version are a feature- you can disable it with --disable-renaming to ICU's configure.